# Hidden div remain visible in refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form that will show hidden div when category is selected in a select tag.

What I want is when I refresh the page, the contents is still visible and also the checked items is still there.

here is the sample code

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" name="food_type1" id="food_type1">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disable" value="0">SELECT</option>
    <option value="1">Fruits</option>
    <option value="2">Meat</option>
</select>

<div id="food1" style="display: none;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="food1[]" value="Mango">Mango <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="food1[]" value="strawberry">Strawberry
</div>

<div id="food2" style="display: none;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="food2[]" value="Beef">Beef <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="food2[]" value="Pork">Pork <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="food2[]" value="Chicken">Chicken
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#food_type1').on('change', function() {
        if ( this.value == '1') {
            $("#food1").show();
            $("#food2").hide();
        }
        else if ( this.value ==  '2') {
            $("#food2").show();
            $("#food1").hide();
        } else {
            $("#food1").hide();
            $("#food2").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**FIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/bk2ohogj/

Comment: That's the purpose of a `refresh`: reset to the initial state. You must persist your data somewhere (cookies, database...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use Local storage. I've updated your fiddle, however you will not be able to test the refresh while in JSFiddle, so you will have to try the code locally on your machine.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/bk2ohogj/4/

You will have to create a couple functions to implement it. I kept them as simple as possible, so they may not address all your use cases, but this should help you get closer to what you are trying to do:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var storedItems = [];

    //Store selected items
    function storeItem(item) {
        storedItems.push(item);
        localStorage.setItem("storage", storedItems);
    }

    //Remove item
    function removeItem(item) {
        var index = storedItems.indexOf(item);
        storedItems.splice(index, 1);
    }

    //Show list according to Dropdown
    function showList(type) {
        var $food1 = $("#food1");
        var $food2 = $("#food2");

        localStorage.setItem("list", type);

        if ( type == '1') {
            $food1.show();
            $food2.hide();
        } else if ( type ==  '2') {
            $food2.show();
            $food1.hide();
        } else {
            $food1.hide();
            $food2.hide();
        }
    }

    //Get list type
    if (localStorage.getItem("list")) {
        showList(localStorage.getItem("list"));
    }

    //Get stored items
    if (localStorage.getItem("storage")) {
        storedItems = localStorage.getItem("storage");

        $.each(storedItems, function(i, val) {
            $('input[type="checkbox"][value="'+val+'"]').prop("checked", true);
        });
    }

    //Dropdown
    $('#food_type1').on('change', function() {
        showList(this.value);
    });

    //Checkbox
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            storeItem(this.val())
        } else {
            removeItem(this.val());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Sir what if there is 2 dropdown menu, are they going to remain visible

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a mechanism to remember the states and dynamically set them on page re/load. You can use sessions (if you are using a server language to generate the pages) or cookies in your scripts. It depends on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the states on the server in the db.  Whenever the state changes, send an update to the back end which will store the state and return the state.  You should use this state to populate the form.

You can use HTML5 Local storage on the browser to retain the states.  However, ensure you handle this carefully, per user.  Whenever the page reloads, read the state from the local storage and populate the form.  In case you have security concerns, be aware that users of the browser can see the content of the local storage.

Comment: The problem is I dont know how to implent the localstorage

Comment: It's quite simple, please check the examples here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp